# Java GSON Json partial parsing

Tags: java, json, gson

Say I have a JSON object representing an entity (can be any entity) like so:

```
{
    "entity_id": "1",
    "entity_name": "employee",
    "entity_json": {
        "employee_id": "e01",
        "employee_name": "john",
        "employee_phone_numbers": [
            "1234567",
            "8765433"
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that `entity_json` can represent different entities having different structures as long as it is a valid JSON. For example, the following is another entity's representation:

```
{
    "entity_id": "1",
    "entity_name": "invoice",
    "entity_json": {
        "invoice_id": "1011",
        "items": {
            "item_id": "1",
            "quantity": "3",
            "price": "$100"
        },
        "date": "01-01-2020",
        "customer": {
            "id": "3",
            "address": {
                "street": "some_street",
                "country": "CZ",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to partially parse this JSON into an Entity POJO using Gson in Java. That is, I'll have an entity POJO like the one shown below:

```
public class Entity {
    private String entity_id;
    private String entity_name;
    private String entity_json;  // <-- entity_json is a String

    // getters and setters
}


/*
 * entity_json (for employee) = "{ \"employee_id\": \"1\", \"employee... }"
 * entity_json (for invoice) = "{ \"invoice_id\": \"1011\", \"items... }"
 */
```

and I'm planning on performing any operation on `entity_json` using JsonPath.

Is there any way I can achieve this WITHOUT having to explicitly set `entity_json` in the JSON structure as a string with escapes?

Any help is appreciated here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using a `String` for your `entity_json` by using Gson's `JsonObject`.

Here is my revised `Entity` class:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class MyEntity {

    private String entity_id;
    private String entity_name;
    private JsonObject entity_json;

    // getters and setters not shown

}
```

Then you can populate instances as follows:

```
MyEntity myEntityOne = new Gson().fromJson(JSON_ONE, MyEntity.class);
MyEntity myEntityTwo = new Gson().fromJson(JSON_TWO, MyEntity.class);

System.out.println(myEntityOne.getEntity_json());
System.out.println(myEntityTwo.getEntity_json());
```

In the above code, `JSON_ONE` and `JSON_TWO` are just strings containing the two sample JSONs from your question.

The console prints out the following (snipped for brevity):

```
{"employee_id":"e01","employee_name":"john","employee_phone_numbers":["1234567","8765433"]}
{"invoice_id":"1011","items":{"item_id":"1","quantity":"3","price":"$100"},"date":"01-01-2020"...
```

You can, of course, now use Gson to further manipulate each `entity_json` field as needed, since each one is itself a valid JSON object.

Comment: Using `JsonObject` did indeed turn out to be a much better way to handle this -- thanks @andrewjames!